# stderr redirection is causing read command to not print output

Tags: bash, scripting, stderr

A code as

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1 4>&2
exec 1>/tmp/stdout.log
exec 2>/tmp/stderr.log
PS4='+ (Line $LINENO) '
set -x
echo "This goes to /tmp/stdout.log"
echo "This goes to /tmp/stderr.log" 1>&2
cmd1="$(uname -a)"
cmd2="$(uname +-a)"

exec 1>&3
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Please do manually Installation of package ,Press any key to continue"



exec 1>&3 2>&4
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

I tried to restore `exec 1>&3` so read is echo but its not showing when i do normal `echo "hello"` it shows but not with `read`.

For selective places in code where I want to user intervention I restore output handling but instead the script waits for command to enter and then execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting `read` to print to `stdout`, but it prints to `stderr` as demonstrated by this command:

```
> read -p "prompt" 2>/dev/null # this command will print nothing
```

Look in your `/tmp/stderr.log`. The missing prompt will be in there.

To restore the ability of `read` to print to your screen, instead of restoring `stdout`, you need to restore `stderr`:

```
exec 2>&4
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Please do manually Installation of package ,Press any key to continue"
```

Alternatively, as noted in the comments, instead of restoring `stderr` with a separate command, you can restore it just for the `read` command:

```
read -n 1 -s -r -p "<shortened for clarity>" 2>&4
```

Comment: I don't want to write to null or file instead it should display on cli as it is.

Comment: @lazereyes So redirect it to the terminal: `read ... 2>/dev/tty`

Comment: @lazereyes Please read the answer. The sample code is meant to demonstrate and reproduce the problem, not to solve it.

Comment: @lazereyes The example I gave was just to demonstrate that `read` prints to `stderr`. It wasn't meant as a fix for your script.

Comment: @MikeHolt A complete answer should explain what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar Not necessarily. It depends on the question.

Comment: @melpomene The main exceptions I can think of are homework questions, where figuring it out is the goal.

Comment: @Barmar I assumed the answer would be obvious once he realized what the problem was. But no worries, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I would do the restoration just for the specific command, rather than using `exec`. `read ... 2>&4`

Comment: @MikeHolt downside of restoring with `exec 2>&4` in with the stdout the error is also appended like `+ (Line 14) read 1 -s -r -p 'Please do manually Installation of package ,Press any ey to continue'`

Comment: @lazereyes I'm pretty sure that's just from your `set -x`. With your original script, if you look in `/tmp/stderr.log`, you will see the full command with the `+ (Line 14)`, but below that you should also see the missing prompt repeated by itself, from when `read` printed it.

Comment: @lazereyes I understand. I was just noting that the extra output you mention is just from your `set -x`. If you aren't planning to leave the `set -x` in there permanently, then it won't matter which method you choose to restore `stderr`. Restoring it with a separate `exec` command also allows the `set -x` output through, which is why you see that difference. If you are planning to leave `set -x` in the script permanently, then by all means use the `read ... 2>&4` method.